# how to get fb user email using new php sdk

Tags: php, facebook

i have asked the extended permission for user's primary email address. but, i can't find user's email from decoded fb signed_request. how to get user's email from new php sdk after user grants the extended permission for email address?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use something like:

```
$facebook->api('/me?fields=email');
```

And the result:

```
Array
(
    [email] => XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    [id] => 579187142
)
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** Facebook gives the user the choice **NOT** to give your application the **real** email! so you have to be careful about this!

Comment: Do you have any idea why can that line throw Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user. thrown in base_facebook.php on line 970. Thanks!

Comment: Make sure to include the scope for email:

`$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'email'));`

Comment: This also works with `$facebook->get()` To include additional fields, delimit them with commas: `$facebook->api('/me?fields=name,email');`